# Android- onItemClick passing the right value to intent

Tags: android, android-intent, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

How can get the right value to be passed to my intent from my GridView. It seems I've doing this the wrong way. So here's what I did:

in my MainActivity:

```
CategoryRowItem category;
.
.  
.
//after parsing from json
 category = new CategoryRowItem(catId, catName);
 categoryItems.add(category);

 gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
 final CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, categoryItems);
 gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            String categoryId = category.getCatId(); // i think this not right
            String categoryName = category.getCatName();
            System.out.println("CAT ID: " +categoryId);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShopListActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("catID", categoryId);
            intent.putExtra(CATEGORY, categoryName);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

my CategoryRowItem class: 
This has getters and setters

```
    public String getCatId(){
    return catId;
}

public String getCatName(){
    return catName;
}
    public void setCatId(String cId){
    this.catId = cId;
}

public void setCatName(String name){
    this.catName = name;
}
```

So, how can i get the right value like catID, or catName of the item clicked>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position` will tell you which item in the list was clicked/selected, and using that you can get your `CategoryRowItem` and its details.

```
CategoryRowItem category = categoryItems.get(position); // Add this line here.
String categoryId = category.getCatId(); // Now this will be right.
String categoryName = category.getCatName();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        String categoryId = categoryItems.get(position).getCatId(); // i think this not right
        String categoryName = categoryItems.get(position).getCatName();
        System.out.println("CAT ID: " +categoryId);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShopListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("catID", categoryId);
        intent.putExtra(CATEGORY, categoryName);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

replace this code with your grid listener